# Setting a cookie with a webpack-dev-server client and hapi API

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a ReactJS client running webpack-dev-server on `localhost:3000`. It connects to a Hapi API server on `localhost:8080` and I'm trying to provide a basic cookie using `hapi-auth-jwt2` (I've also tried `hapi-auth-cookie` with equal results).

I can see the response header provides a valid `set-cookie` header and everything looks okay, but all my browser tests ignore it and the cookie is never set (verified by checking `document.cookie` and using the browser tools like Chrome's Application tab). When I connect directly to the API server with Postman, it picks up the `set-cookie` header correctly and stores it so I think it's just some kind of domain/port/host configuration issue.

As a simple test, I tried deploying to our ec2 environment but that didn't help. The ec2 environment is similar, with one instance serving the client and another instance serving the API. I've also tried modifying my local `hosts` file to redirect a domain like `127.0.0.1    example.com` and providing the `domain=.example.com` field in the cookie, but that also didn't help.

I think I'm just missing something basic but I don't know what it is. See below for response/request headers on login.

**Request Headers**

`POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 47
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Authorization: undefined
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9`

**Response Headers**

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
authorization: <jwt token>
vary: origin,accept-encoding
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-expose-headers: WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
set-cookie: cookie=token; Max-Age=604800; Expires=Wed, 16 May 2018 21:11:23 GMT; SameSite=Lax; Path=/
cache-control: no-cache
content-encoding: gzip
Date: Wed, 09 May 2018 21:11:23 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

Answer (score 0):

[http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware), which webpack-dev-server uses, has [options](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options) for cookie domain/path rewrites.

You should see if those satisfy your needs. Otherwise you can also manually parse and reset cookies in the `onProxyRes` callback. [Here](https://github.com/ktmud/http-proxy-middleware-secure-cookies/blob/487946ff86e073081635fdecfe140413d263cce2/src/secureCookieProxy.ts#L168-L210) is an example.